# Checking multiple MySQL columns against a single value with LIKE

Tags: php, mysql, sql

`SELECT *
FROM   tableName
WHERE  'value%' IN/LIKE (col1, col2, col3, col4)`

I want to find single value in multiple columns with like condition on value. That value with 'value%' must be found in col1 OR col2 OR ..... like this.

I have a big query with 10 columns to find, so need optimised query for this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Seems like a less good table design if you need to search so many columns...

Comment: you have to you "OR" condition for each "LIKE" column

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tableName
WHERE  
col1 LIKE 'value%' OR
col2 LIKE 'value%' OR ..
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is going to be extremely slow on a big table, since MySQL can only use a single index per table, so from the 2nd criterion on no indexes can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Either you create a nice long query with union for each of the searches (MySQL is not really good at optimising or conditions) or you need to create [fulltext index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html) on all the columns involved and do a [Boolean search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html).

The union query will look like the following:

```
select * from tablename where col1 LIKE 'value%'
union
select * from tablename where col2 LIKE 'value%'
...
```

The Boolean search on the fulltext index would look like as follows:

```
select * FROM tablename WHERE MATCH (col1,col2,...)
AGAINST ('+value*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```